# sort text file and and sort the number of listing

Tags: python, sorting, split, file-handling

I want to sort a text file every time a new input was added, but I want the numbers for each name also get sorted. but when I used split() I get errors :  I/O operation on closed file.
am I putting it in a wrong place? or should I not reread the lines. I tried to just add file.sort() at the end but since each line start with number and it was already sorted in that way.

```
while True:

file = open('s:/not a test.txt','r')
lst = file.readlines()

file.close()
n = input("enter name and familyname: ")
if n:
    length = len(lst)+1
    file = open('s:/not a test.txt','a')
    
    file.write(str(length)+'. '+n+'\n')
    file.close()
else:
    break
eachline = file.readlines()
data = eachline.split(".")
lines.sort()
for line in lst:
    file.write(str(length)+'. '+n+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that your file is closed and you are tyring to sort values of a closed file.
Here is the alternative. You may adapt this one to yours:

I open the file in read+ mode which is what you could use to append the content. I am using `with open` instead of just `open` so that I do not need to force close the file myself. It takes care by itself when the act is done.
When the file is read its content, the code executes the input method and it iterates in the while loop until you do not enter anything and goes into the `else` part of the decision when you do not enter anything. As you enter the `else` part, the list is then sorted and printed out and the loop breaks out.

```
while True:
    with open('one.txt', 'r+') as file:
        lst = file.readlines()
        print(lst)
        n = input("number")
        if n:
            ln = len(lst)+1
            file.write(n + '\n')
            # eachline = file.readlines()
        else:
            print(list)
            sortedlines = sorted(lst)
            print(sortedlines)
            break
```

here is the output that I got:

```
['1\n', '4\n', '3\n']
number8
['1\n', '4\n', '3\n', '8\n']
number7
['1\n', '4\n', '3\n', '8\n', '7\n']
number
<class 'list'>
['1\n', '3\n', '4\n', '7\n', '8\n']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: thank you so much, I have question about this part: with open('one.txt', 'r+') as file: does it act like a condition?

Comment: sorry if I'm asking too many question but what is the difference between "r" and "r+" ?

Comment: `r` reads the file from where the cursor is, while `r+` starts from the beginning of the file. All I know is this much about `r` and `r+`. You may try using `r` and see if it works. I didn't try it

Answer (score 0):

so I made some changes from the information and help that I got here from Anand Gautam. thank you so much.

```
while True:

with open ('s:/not a test.txt', 'r') as file:
    lst = file.readlines()
    n = input("enter name and familyname: ")
    if n:
        file.write(n+'\n')
    else:
        count= 1
        m = sorted(lst)
        with open ('s:/not a test.txt', 'w') as f:
            for eachline in m:
                file.write(str(count)+'.'+ eachline+'\n')
                count+=1
        

        break
```

so, I brought the sorting and numbering part after the inputs have finished. it will get the new inputs and everything and then sort the text file. I'm not sure if it will have problem but this is close to what I had in mind.